# How to insert image from the Internet into Bitbucket (bitbucket.org) pull request?

Tags: bitbucket

How to insert image from the Internet into Bitbucket (bitbucket.org) pull request?

Bitbucket currently only allows to attach images but I'd like to simply link to an external resource so in case image changes there then it's reflected in Bitbucket.

How to achieve this?

(Research on how it was achieved and a solution is provided in the answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not trivial and most likely Atlassian didn't want this in their bitbucket.org setup. So it seems to be the undocumented feature. But following these steps allows to insert an image from the Internet by its link:

1. Copy image URL. Let's use https://www.plantuml.com/plantuml/svg/SyfFKj2rKt3CoKnELR1Io4ZDoSa70000 image URL for our test.
2. Paste image into comment field:
   [image]
3. Press spacebar after the URL so it gets converted into the link:
   [image]
4. Enclose URL with "!":
   [image]
5. Press "Save".

---

#### Editing comment

Challenging is now to edit URL in the comment since the link is now displayed as an image in the edit area. But you can simply use browser's "Copy image address" menu item from the pop-up menu, modify the link as you wish, delete the image and retry the same instruction above.